# convertir dolar JS

Tags: javascript

```js
module.exports = function coinConvert(usDollars) {
  var arr = [];
  var peruvianSoles /* tu código aquí */;
  var mexicanPesos /* tu código aquí */;
  var chileanPesos /* tu código aquí */;

  // Añade el monto equivalente en soles
  arr.push(/* tu código aquí */);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos mexicanos
  arr.push(/* tu código aquí */);

  // Añade el monto equivalente en pesos chilenos
  arr.push(/* tu código aquí */);

  return arr;
};
```

> Me pueden ayudar con esto, por favor. Es un ejercicio muy simple de
>   Javascript.

**DATOS:**

soles = dólares * 3.25

pesosMexicanos = dólares * 18

pesosChilenos = dólares * 660

**EJEMPLO:**

```
function coinConvert(dollar = 50) {
  soles = dollar * 3.25;    
  pesosMexicanos = dollar * 18;    
  pesosChilenos = dollar * 660;    
  console.log(soles, pesosMexicanos, pesosChilenos); 
  // --> [162.5, 900, 33000]
}
```

Comment: Hola @ValeriaCossio. Este sitio no funciona así, aquí no se resuelven ejercicios, se resuelven dudas puntuales de código. Para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio te recomiendo que leas el [tour] y [ask]. Si reformulas la pregunta de acuerdo a las normas del sitio será bien recibida

Comment: Es sencillo, parecido a la funcion que tienes, introduces dollar por parametro, y haces un return de pesosMexicanos tras la multiplicación/division. Lo que no se es que tiene que ver tu código de arriba con lo que has puesto abajo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como he puesto en el comentario, puedes pasarle a la función los parametros de la moneda a la que quieres convertir y la cantidad. Y luego dependiendo de la moneda pues darle el valor a la multiplicación. Finalmente hacer un return de ese resultado.

De esta manera podras llamar a la funcion para cualquiera de las monedas o con cualquier cantidad todas las veces que quieras.

Puedes hacer un console log como lo que he hecho yo, o guardar resultado en una variable para luego tratarla por ejemplo.

```js
console.log(coinConvert("Soles",10));

function coinConvert(moneda,cantidad) {
  switch(moneda){
    case "Soles":
      moneda=3.25;
      break;
    case "Pesos Mexicanos":
      moneda=18;
      break;
    case "Pesos Chilenos ":
      moneda=660;
      break;
  }
  
  var resultado = moneda * cantidad;
  return resultado;
}
```

Comment: nunca explicó que problema tenía, así que esta pregunta es de baja calidad, yo creo que lo que quiere es simplemente regresar los datos en un arreglo `[soles, pesosMexicanos, pesosChilenos]`